# How to customize Emmet (snippets.json) for codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, emmet

I am trying to build a simple in-browser prototyping tool using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) and [Emmet](http://emmet.io), which could be easily updated to future versions of libraries.
It works, but the next thing I need is to allow keymap and snippets customization without touching the lib files.

Refering to http://docs.emmet.io/customization/

> Emmet offers wide range of tweaks you can use to fine-tune your plugin experience. Almost all officially developed editor plugins (except PSPad and browser-based) has extensions support: a special folder where you can put json and js files to extend Emmet. Please refer to README file bundled with your editor’s plugin to find out where Emmet looks for extensions.

Great ! But ...  unfortunately, I cannot find such information in https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror. Hold on ... ok, that's "browser-based".

I found in `dist/emmet.js` a function `loadExtensions: function(fileList)` but I'm not sure how to use it, or if it is the right way to go.

*Note:* In main stream https://github.com/emmetio/emmet , snippets are now moved to a separate file `snippets.json`, which sounds nice for maintenance and reference, but that is not (yet?) the case for the codemirror plugin.

I tried:

```
emmetPlugin.emmet.loadExtensions(['snippets.json']);
```

(also with full path to file), but got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'readFileSync' emmet.js:18352
_.extend._read emmet.js:18352
_.extend.readText emmet.js:18376
bound emmet.js:2006
next emmet.js:22295
loadExtensions emmet.js:22337
window.onload (index):62
```

The snippets file is just a copy of the one in main emmet project.

**Current versions**:

- emmet:  Jun 20, 2014, [SHA 0edf759560353865b9619270752ffec6b2450977](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/tree/0edf759560353865b9619270752ffec6b2450977)
- emmet/codemirror: Apr 29, 2014, [SHA 16a52454aeba7ae0520fd85df3079f39f796109c](https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror/tree/16a52454aeba7ae0520fd85df3079f39f796109c)
- CodeMirror: Aug 05, 2014, [SHA b4ecdded6357d0364fc9a51240675c9f040f039c](http://www.pixelmonkey.org/2013/03/13/rapid-web-prototyping-with-lightweight-tools)

Could you help me ?

### Next try

Following Sergey's proposal, here's what I tried, using [jquery's ajax facility](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
window.onload = function() {
    // ...
    $.getJSON( "snippets.json", function( data ) {
        emmetPlugin.emmet.loadUserData(data);
    });
    // ...
};
```

With *`file:` protocol*, the page raises `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` exception.

So it needs to be loaded from some HTTP server like

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

It now loads without error in console, but my new snippet doesn't work.
I picked it from the [excellent talk from A. Montalenti](http://www.pixelmonkey.org/2013/03/13/rapid-web-prototyping-with-lightweight-tools) which made me discover *[Emmet.io](http://emmet.io)*, in his [emmet.js](https://github.com/amontalenti/rapid-web/blob/master/static/preview/emmet.js#L13543), where it worked perfectly:

```
{
    "abbreviations": {
         "bootstrap": "html>(head>meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{${1:Bootstrapped}}+link[href=\"../css/lib/bootstrap.css\"]+link[href=\"../css/lib/bootstrap-responsive.css\"]+script[src=\"../js/lib/bootstrap.js\"]+script[src=\"../js/lib/jquery.js\"])+body>div.container",
    }
}
```

although default snippets like `doc4` work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [`loadExtensions` method](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/emmet.js#L106), you’ll see that it actually reads given file list, combines them and passes to [`loadUserData` method](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/emmet.js#L218).

So you have two options:

1. Since there are no file system in browser, you have to implement your own, AJAX-based: see [file module description](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/plugin/file.js)
2. Use methods like `loadUserData`, `loadSnippets` etc. and pass plain JSON file.

Comment: Hello Sergey, Thank you very much for your answer, I couldn't answer before because I had no internet last few days. I am going to explore your pointers right now :)